# Amazon SES/Mailgun and Reverse DNS lookups for email

Tags: reverse-dns, amazon-ses

I am working with a client who sends out emails to clients (password reset, employee invitations, etc.) using Mailgun, but we are getting a some emails blocked due to reverse DNS lookups for the Mailgun ip address.

I have looked into using AWS Simple Email Service (SES) to send these emails instead, but haven't found any documentation on reverse DNS lookups for this service. I know EC2 has reverse DNS lookups (with Route53), but that EC2 ip address ranges are usually blocked for email due to spam concerns-- so it looks like we can't setup our own mail server using EC2.

Is there a way to setup reverse DNS for AWS SES or will we have the same problem of reverse DNS lookup failures if we switch to AWS SES?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per AWS SES FAQ:

> Amazon SES users do not need to set up reverse DNS records. Amazon Web Services manages the IP addresses used by Amazon SES, and provides reverse DNS records for these addresses.

As a side note, i send communication to clients through Amazon SES for a few years, and have never received any email-blocked statuses regarding reverse proxy.